# Writing and reading Matlab Matrices

Tags: matlab, io

I have a simple matrix

```
  A =     
    0.21415   2             3
    5         7.453435      9
```

I would like to write it in a file and read it later.

Should I use `save myfile A` and `load` commands or [`readmtx`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/map/ref/readmtx.html) ?

Comment: `readmtx` appears to be designed mostly for when the matrix already exists externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note that you can use `save -ascii varname` to get a textual representation of the variable. The default is a `.mat` file which is more efficient but not human readable and harder to interface with external programs.

Comment: For loading it back must I use something in particular with ascii ?

Comment: Nope. Just `load filename` or use the functional form `myvar = load('filename')`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you would consider 'best', but simple code and common practice would indeed just be:

```
A = magic(4)
save filename A
clear
load filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. use `save` and `load`.